# Angular FormArray setValue with data from Service

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, formarray

I have a Problem with FormArray and could need some help.
I have a form with variable FormArray and it works and I can send the data to the backend.
The problem is, that I cant set the values from the data I receive from the backend.

**This is the Typescript Code**:

```js
this.form = this.fb.group({
  title: new FormControl("",[Validators.required]),
  actors: new FormArray([])
})

this.moviesService.getMovie(this.movieId).subscribe(movieData => {
  this.movie = movieData;
  this.form.patchValue({
    title: this.movie.title,
    actors: this.movie.actors,           
  })
})
```

**then on button click in html I call this functions**:

```js
addActor(){
  const actorsForm = this.fb.group({
    actor: '',
    role: ''
  })
  this.actors.push(actorsForm);
}

removeActor(i: number){
  this.actors.removeAt(i);
}
```

**And the HTML:**

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (submit)="onSubmit()">
  <table  formArrayName="actors">
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">Besetzung:</th>
      <th width="150px">
        <button type="button" mat-stroked-button color="primary" (click)="addActor()">Hinzufügen +</button>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let actor of form.get('actors')['controls']; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
      <td>
        Darsteller:
        <input type="text" formControlName="actor" class="form-control">
      </td>
      <td>
        Rolle:
        <input type="text" formControlName="role" class="form-control">
      </td>
      <td>
        <button (click)="removeActor(i)" mat-stroked-button color="warn">Remove</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="submit">Film speichern</button>
</form>
```

So my question is:
How do I get the Data from the `movieService` in the `actors` Array?

`actors: this.movie.actors` doesn't work, I know I have to iterate through the array but don't know how.

Edit:
Ok, I saw I got the first object from the array but if I add more actors it will just show the first.

Comment: Hi, can you attach the JSON data returned from API that will use to patch for FormArray? Thanks.

Comment: Can you sow us your error Message ?

Comment: hi. sure. it looks like this: [{"id":5,"role":"test","actor":"test"},{"id":6,"role":"test","actor":"test2"}] there is no error cause the form is empty

Comment: you should pass array of form groups, like your `addActor` method does. so it will look like: actors: this.movie.actors.map(({actor, role, id}) => this.fb.group({
      actor,
      role,
      id
    }))

Comment: if i try to map i got this error: Property 'role' does not exist on type 'String'.

Comment: It seems that type of `movieData` is `{
    title: string,
    actors: string,           
  }`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Assumption**:

Expected that the API response data received will be:

```
{
  "title": "James Bond 007",
  "actors": [
    { "id": 5, "role": "test", "actor": "test" },
    { "id": 6, "role": "test", "actor": "test2" }
  ]
}
```

---

I don't think that can directly `patchValue` for `FormArray`. Instead, iterate `movie.actors` with `map` in order to push `FormGroup` to `actors` `FormArray`.

```js
this.movie.actors.map(
  (actor: any) => {
    const actorsForm = this.fb.group({
      actor: actor.actor,
      role: actor.role,
    });

    this.actors.push(actorsForm);
  }
);

this.form.patchValue({
  title: this.movie.title,
});
```

---

**Note**: Since you implement `actors` getter, you can simplify

```
form.get('actors')['controls']
```

to:

```
actors.controls
```

> HTML

```
<tr
  *ngFor="let actor of actors.controls; let i = index"
  [formGroupName]="i"
>

</tr>
```

[Sample Solution on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ufkebx?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: this works. tyvm. so the problem was that i thought i could map through actors in form patchvalue and also thanks for the simplify tip